# chat collection query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

```
{
  "_id": "654f4d7cbb027c35a0b90529",
  "msg": "test message",
  "createdat": "2023-11-11T09:46:41.872Z",
  "dateseen": "2023-11-11T09:55:56.596Z",
  "fromid": "eb78a1f79938f5eb193b63fc13b3250",
  "toid": "7b987d98718041abb3b9a85b5c96214a",
  "deleted1": false,
  "deleted1at": null,
  "deleted2": false,
  "deleted2at": null,
  "type": 1
}
```

I have a chats collections like the one above. From this collection, I need a query that sends a certain userID to the chat DM and retrieves the last messaged people, last message and the number of unread messages. I tried a lot but I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help?

I need an output similar to this;

```
{
    "body": [
        {
            "id": "c5e8b02a94984fe38e7ff35131890b55",
            "unSeenMsgCount": 0,
            "lastMessage": {
                "fromId": "eb78a1f74f274353b63fc13b3250",
                "toId": "c5e8b02a94984fe7ff35131890b55",
                "message": "string",
                "dateSent": 1704889808607,
                "type": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "header": null
}
```

This was the code that came closest to the solution, but it still did not fully meet my needs. Not only are unseen messages coming in incorrectly, but also two different chats are being returned from to id and from id.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "fromid": userID, "deleted1": false },
        { "toid": userID, "deleted2": false }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $or: [
              { $and: [{ $eq: ["$fromid", userID] }, { $ne: ["$toid", userID] }] },
              { $and: [{ $eq: ["$toid", userID] }, { $ne: ["$fromid", userID] }] }
            ]
          },
          then: "$toid",
          else: "$fromid"
        }
      },
      lastMessage: {
        $last: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $or: [
                { $and: [{ $eq: ["$toid", userID] }, { $ne: ["$fromid", userID] }] },
                { $and: [{ $eq: ["$fromid", userID] }, { $ne: ["$toid", userID] }] }
              ]
            },
            then: "$$ROOT",
            else: null
          }
        }
      },
      unseenCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$toid", userID] },
                { $eq: ["$dateseen", null] }
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { "lastMessage.createdat": -1 }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: ["$lastMessage", { "unSeenMsgCount": "$unseenCount" }]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: offset
  },
  {
    $limit: limit
  }
])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "last messaged people, last message and the number of unread messages"? What have you tried so far and what is the specific error you are encountering?

Comment: Actually, you can think of it as a WhatsApp or Instagram messages screen. I tried various queries, I was able to retrieve the last userID messages I sent, but instead of showing the last message sent by the other party, it always returned only the userID I sent as a parameter. I can't post the code because the comment is limited.

Comment: We don't know which field should we use to get the information and **expected output**. And you should provide such information through [edit]ting your question, instead of putting them in comments.

Comment: I continued to the question section and added the response I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a userId variable that you want to query for, and considering your collection structure, Maybe you can you like this

```
db.chats.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            { fromid: userId },
            { toid: userId }
        ],
        deleted1: false, // Assuming this flag is for message deletion status
        deleted2: false
    }
},
{
    $sort: { createdat: -1 }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: ["$fromid", userId] },
                then: "$toid",
                else: "$fromid"
            }
        },
        lastMessage: { $first: "$msg" },
        unreadCount: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [
                    { $and: [{ $ne: ["$fromid", userId] }, { $eq: ["$dateseen", null] }] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I run this incomplete query it doesn't return the last messages correctly.